# Load image via ajax in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to load a image via ajax i.e get contents of image via ajax and show this as a image. I Know how to do the later part but

1. how do i get the ajax data/blob into a variable
2. how can i make a ajax call in a directive

I want the actual content of image not just src/url. I want to do this to overcome the CSP restriction of chrome apps

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: I think that ajax call in directive is wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460684/how-to-read-a-binary-data-in-angularjs

Comment: @Dave thanks for first part... how about second

Comment: @aWebDeveloper You can bind the directive to a button, bind a `click` event listener to the element (which is the button), and trigger the ajax call function using angular's `$http` service

Comment: why would you need to make ajax call in directive? Even if you do there is no difference in approach

Comment: You should really make ajax calls in a service.  You can use the `link` option of your directive to call the service, and then bind to the variable when the result comes back.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: To load image directly using base64

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}}" />
```

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1koLs9fh/2/

To update URL

You need to bind the `ng-src` to some variable. On AJAX response update this variable.

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">                
            <img ng-src="http://{{url}}"/>
            <button ng-click="loadImages()">load images</button>
        </div>
    </div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl',
    function ($scope) {        
        $scope.loadImages = function() {
        $scope.url = 'cdn1.www.st-hatena.com/users/ho/howdy39/profile.gif';       
        }
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1koLs9fh/

Comment: never want to use `src` ... browser will make funky requests with uncompiled url which will of course be 404

Comment: agreed. Use ng-src. Just an example.

Comment: i don't want the src but actual image in src. i.e make ajax call and get the actual image not just src.

Comment: you mean actual bytes?

Comment: @aWebDeveloper need to transpose that image file to a base64 dataUri then. Doesn't really make sense sending image itself if it is stored web accessible directory

Comment: @charlietfl yup i know but how do i make ajax call in directive

Comment: answer is updated for loading image from base64 string. Above comment - that's a separate question now.